# Office365 Apps Issue

Tags: outlook, office365

I am not able to access microsoft apps ( Outlook & Teams) on mobile phone.
I have already enrolled to the company portal.
Following error is shown:

**your sign-in was successful but your admin requires your device to be managed android**

Request Id: 25ac9c8f-68b9-4223-b710-5d9c1c2e1a00Correlation Id: db8c643a-a904-46ad-99ba-6aca13870a8aTimestamp: 2021-03-03T15:30:25.029ZApp name: Outlook MobileApp ID: 27922004-5251-4030-b22d-91ecd9a37ea4IP address: 42.111.21.226Device identifier: f68c6677-8bcb-4d23-b46c-b2771635fd2bDevice platform: AndroidDevice state: Registered